# Transformation of the Lorentz factor when a relativistic particle partially absorbs energy from a photon?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, kinematics, inertial-frames

I came across this paper ([on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.09581)) that says when a particle with high Lorentz factor $\Gamma$ meets a radiation beam and absorbs some energy $\epsilon$, it's Lorentz factor transforms like so (Eq. (1) of the text):

$$\Gamma_1 \approx \frac{\Gamma}{\sqrt{1 + 4\Gamma^2\epsilon/mc^2}}\tag{1}$$

Even though the author states it's "immediate" from energy-momentum conservation and proceeds to give a physical description of what this means for the interaction, it's not at all obvious to me how to derive such a result, nor what kind of approximations went into deriving it.

Could someone help me derive it please? Answers with detailed steps are appreciated. TIA.

**EDIT:** Thanks for the detailed answers! I'll award the bounty to @AlexGhorbal for the initial take that inspired the detailed answer by @robphy, and accept the response from @robphy for the relevant physical intuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(See UPDATE below)

---

Inspired by @AlexGhorbal 's attempt,
I present a trigonometric derivation of Alex's result with an approximation used only at the last step.

(I was playing around with the equations... and the result fell out.)

*The methods shown here are useful for other problems in special relativity,*
not just the question in the OP.

[image: robphy-spacetimetrig]

I'm going to use rapidity $\theta$, where $v=\tanh\theta$ and thus

 the Lorentz factor $\Gamma=\cosh\theta$ and $v\Gamma =\sinh\theta$ and the Doppler factor $k=\exp\theta$.

Using components in the lab frame, energy-momentum conservation yields
\begin{align}
N\cosh\phi &=M\cosh\theta+\epsilon\\
N\sinh\phi &=M\sinh\theta-\epsilon
\end{align}
By addition, we obtain
$$\boxed{
\begin{align}
N\exp\phi &=M\exp\theta,
\end{align}
}
$$
which is essentially the Doppler Effect, where $K=\exp(\theta-\phi)=(N/M)$ is relative-Bondi-Doppler factor.

By subtraction, we obtain
$$
\boxed{\begin{align}
N\exp(-\phi) &=M\exp(-\theta)+2\epsilon,
\end{align}}
$$
[The above boxed equations represent
**"energy-momentum conservation in light-cone coordinates"** (in the eigenspace)]

We wish to eliminate $N$ (the mass of the final particle resulting from the absorption of the photon)

By **multiplication**,
$$\boxed{N^2=M^2+2\epsilon M\exp\theta}$$
which is the related to Alex's $\Rightarrow$ equation, *but without using any approximation*.

(Of course, this is the square-norm of the 4-momentum equation
$\tilde N=\tilde M+\tilde \gamma$.)

Re-write this as
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{N}{M}\right)^2 &=1+\frac{2\epsilon}{M}\exp\theta \\
K^2 &=1+\frac{2\epsilon}{M}\exp\theta \\
(\exp(\theta-\phi))^2 &=1+\frac{2\epsilon}{M}\exp\theta \\
\end{align}

(This is the a-ha moment!) Taking square-roots,
\begin{align}
\exp(\theta-\phi) &=\sqrt{1+\frac{2\epsilon}{M}\exp\theta} \\
\end{align}
and solving for $\exp\phi$, we have
\begin{align}
\exp\phi &=\frac{\exp{\theta}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2\epsilon}{M}\exp\theta}} \\
\end{align}
This is a **physics relationship** between the lab frame's Doppler factors of the initial and final particle, the mass $M$ of initial particle and the photon energy $\epsilon$ in the lab frame. That is,
$$
\boxed{\boxed{
\begin{align}
k_N &=\frac{k_M}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2\epsilon}{M}k_M}} \\
\end{align}
}}
$$
**which is an exact result.**

---

### **UPDATE**

The double-boxed result is obtained more directly by **division** of the first pair of boxed equations, rather than multiplication then some additional algebra to eliminate $N$.

\begin{align}
\boxed{\exp(2\phi) 
= \frac{M\exp\theta}{M\exp(-\theta)+2\epsilon}}
&= \frac{\exp(2\theta)}{1+\frac{2\epsilon}{M}\exp\theta}\\
\exp\phi 
&= \frac{\exp\theta}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2\epsilon}{M}\exp\theta}},
\end{align}
which is the double-boxed equation (when the Doppler-$k$ is introduced)!

In summary,

- express energy-momentum conservation in light-cone coordinates
  (by adding and subtracting energy-momentum conservation in rectangular coordinates).
- divide those equations (which relate the square-of-$N$'s-Doppler-factor with $M$'s-Doppler-factor, mass $M$, and the lab-frame energy $\epsilon$ of the beam 
  -- this is Mermin's aspect-ratio of the "causal diamond of N" (Mermin's "light rectangle")

  to obtain the square of the double-boxed-equation
- In the large $\Gamma$ limit, the Doppler-factor $k \approx 2\Gamma$ (as shown below).
- If desired, one could carry out the expansion for $k$ further to get the next order in the approximation in terms of the Lorentz factors $\Gamma$.

---

Note
\begin{align}
k=\exp\theta &=\cosh\theta+\sinh\theta\\
&= \cosh\theta+\sqrt{\cosh^2\theta-1}\\
&=\Gamma+\sqrt{\Gamma^2-1}
\end{align}

---

Now, because the particles are assumed to have large Lorentz factors,
we can make the **approximation** that:
*for large $\Gamma$, we have $k\approx 2\Gamma$,*
and thus,
\begin{align}
2\Gamma_N &\approx \frac{2\Gamma_M}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2\epsilon}{M}(2\Gamma_M)}} \\
\Gamma_N &\approx \frac{\Gamma_M}{\sqrt{1+\frac{4\epsilon}{M}\Gamma_M}} \\
\end{align}
...in agreement with Alex's final result...

 but
**using only one approximation, once [for $k_N$ and $k_M$]

at this last step here at the very end.**

We see the approximate relation between Lorentz-factors
is based on a similar but exact relation between Doppler factors.

Comment: Actually, seeing that you only made one approximation made me realise that I also only made one approximation!

Comment: For the Compton effect (particle at rest), i.e. Γ(0)=1 , Γ(1)=1+Ɛ/mc² , without approximation.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong but I am getting a slightly different answer. The initial particle with mass $m$ and high Lorentz factor $\Gamma\gg 1$ has four-momentum $p^{\mu}\approx\Gamma m c (1,0,0,1)$ while the photon it absorbs has $p_{\gamma}^{\mu}=\frac{\epsilon}{c}(1,0,0,-1)$ assuming a head on collision in the $z$ direction. The particle after it has absorbed the photon has mass $m_1$ and four-momentum $p_1^{\mu}=\Gamma_1m_1(c,0,0,v_1)$ with $v_1$ its unknown velocity. Four-momentum conservation now gives

$$p^{\mu}+p_{\gamma}^{\mu}=p_1^{\mu}$$

and squaring both sides we find

$$p^{\mu}p_{\mu}+2p^{\mu}{p_{\gamma}}_{\mu}+{p_{\gamma}}^{\mu}{p_{\gamma}}_{\mu}={p_1}^{\mu}{p_1}_{\mu}$$

$$\Rightarrow -m^2c^2+2\left[-\Gamma m c\left(\frac{\epsilon}{c}\right)+\Gamma m c\left(\frac{-\epsilon}{c}\right)\right]\approx-m_1^2c^2$$

$$\Rightarrow m_1\approx m\sqrt{1+\frac{4\Gamma\epsilon}{mc^2}}$$

On the other hand, by simple energy conservation we have

$$\Gamma_1 m_1 c^2=\Gamma m c^2+\epsilon\approx\Gamma m c^2$$

assuming $\epsilon\ll\Gamma m c^2$, which is just the same as assuming that $\Gamma_1\gg1$ because if $\epsilon\sim\Gamma m c^2$ then the particle would be significantly slowed and no longer be ultra-relativistic.

Thus we finally get

$$\Gamma_1\approx\Gamma \frac{m}{m_1}\approx\frac{\Gamma}{\sqrt{1+\frac{4\Gamma\epsilon}{mc^2}}}$$

which is nearly what you have given. If you or anyone finds a mistake please let me know. Otherwise the paper might be wrong.